# How to chain multiple 'And' when checking exception with FluentAssertions

Tags: fluent-assertions

I have a unit test that validates that some code throws an exception **and** that **two** properties have the expected value. Here is how I do it:

```
var exception = target.Invoking(t => t.CallSomethingThatThrows())
                    .ShouldThrow<WebServiceException>()
                    .And;

            exception.StatusCode.Should().Be(400);
            exception.ErrorMessage.Should().Be("Bla bla...");
```

I don't like the look of the assertion that must be done in three statements. Is there an elegant way to do it in a single statement? My first intuition was to use something like this:

```
target.Invoking(t => t.CallSomethingThatThrows())
                    .ShouldThrow<WebServiceException>()
                    .And.StatusCode.Should().Be(400)
                    .And.ErrorMessage.Should().Be("Bla bla...");
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As said [here](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/510):

```
target.Invoking(t => t.CallSomethingThatThrows())
      .ShouldThrow<WebServiceException>()
      .Where(e => e.StatusCode == 400)
      .Where(e => e.ErrorMessage == "Bla bla...");
```

Comment: Doesn't this approach result in very barebones failure exceptions?

Answer (score -1):

Not really a direct answer but I note that, if you only have one property of the exception to check, you can use a more fluid syntax like this:

```
target.Invoking(t => t.CallSomethingThatThrows())
      .ShouldThrow<WebServiceException>()
      .Which.StatusCode.Should().Be(400);
```